# Is it possible to know what changed on a mssql database?

Tags: mssql

I'm trying to reverse engineer the mssql database behind an ERP.

I was planning to export the database as a sql file before and after I do a modification in the ERP to be able to `diff` the files. But my files are huge. About 8 GB for the development environment, it would be a lot more for the production one.

I was wondering if there's a better way. Maybe with snapshots or maybe I could enable a log with all SQL queries. Or maybe I could sniff the data on the network.

I'm using Sql Server 2005.

Comment: What do you mean by `reverse engineer the mssql database behind an ERP`? Do you mean you're creating sql for whole database schema with insert scripts for existing data?

Comment: We have an ERP where I work that use our own MSSQL server. I would like to access the ERP's data but I don't know exactly how it's stored in the tables. I can guess but I was thinking it could be easier if I could do something like a snapshot, then do an operation in the ERP (like creating an order for a customer) and then be able to know which data changed since the snapshot (a bit like when we use [diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) with source code).